# Is runtime upgrade needed when changing offchain worker?

Tags: runtime-upgrade, offchain-worker

Suppose I have a blockchain that has been running for some time, and at a certain point, I need to update the offchain worker code. What is the recommended approach for updating the blockchain: swapping the binaries or performing a runtime upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, whenever you do changes in the node code directly its required to replace the binary and starting the chain again. In case of runtime and pallet changes runtime upgrade is sufficient. Since OCWs are part of pallet code RU is enough for that matter.

Comment: For the changes to be picked up by the running OCW, would they need to restart the node?

Comment: So, roughly speaking if we think of the `node/` folder inside the substrate-node-template repo, if something changes there, we need to replace the binary? `pallets` and `runtime` changes require a RU.

Comment: @Bruno i dont think so. But my assumption might be wrong!

Comment: @subuser yes 100%

Comment: @ImmanuelJohn What about dependency updates? For example, the node imports an external service that's located in a new version in another crate? That requires a binary switch I guess